# Android studio is not importing file

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract, tess-two

I am developing app that is text detection using ocr. 
I get the source code from https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR. When i am using latest android studio. I didn't get the import file of TessBaseAPI. I try add tess-two to project modules. But it is not working. How it possible to run, the below shows the source where i wrote.

```
package com.acs.ocr;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.datumdroid.ocr";
public static final String DATA_PATH = Environment
        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/SimpleAndroidOCR/";

public static final String lang = "eng";

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity.java";

protected Button _button;
// protected ImageView _image;
protected EditText _field;
protected String _path;
protected boolean _taken;

protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] paths = new String[]{DATA_PATH, DATA_PATH + "tessdata/"};
    for (String path : paths) {
        File dir = new File(path);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.v(TAG, "ERROR: Creation of directory " + path + " on sdcard failed");
                return;
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "Created directory " + path + " on sdcard");
            }
        }

    }

    if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata")).exists()) {
        try {

            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata");
            //GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DATA_PATH
                    + "tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata");

            // Transfer bytes from in to out
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            //while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            //gin.close();
            out.close();

            Log.v(TAG, "Copied " + lang + " traineddata");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy " + lang + " traineddata " + e.toString());
        }
    }


    // _image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    _field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field);
    _button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    _button.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());

    _path = DATA_PATH + "/ocr.jpg";

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.acs.ocr/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.acs.ocr/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}

public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Starting Camera app");
        startCameraActivity();
    }
}

protected void startCameraActivity() {
    File file = new File(_path);
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.i(TAG, "resultCode: " + resultCode);

    if (resultCode == -1) {
        onPhotoTaken();
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "User cancelled");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean(MainActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState()");
    if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(MainActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN)) {
        onPhotoTaken();
    }
}

protected void onPhotoTaken() {
    _taken = true;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path, options);

    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(_path);
        int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        Log.v(TAG, "Orient: " + exifOrientation);

        int rotate = 0;

        switch (exifOrientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
        }

        Log.v(TAG, "Rotation: " + rotate);

        if (rotate != 0) {

            // Getting width & height of the given image.
            int w = bitmap.getWidth();
            int h = bitmap.getHeight();

            // Setting pre rotate
            Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
            mtx.preRotate(rotate);

            // Rotating Bitmap
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
        }

        // Convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't correct orientation: " + e.toString());
    }

    // _image.setImageBitmap( bitmap );

    Log.v(TAG, "Before baseApi");

    TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    baseApi.setDebug(true);
    baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);
    baseApi.setImage(bitmap);

    String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();

    baseApi.end();

    // You now have the text in recognizedText var, you can do anything with it.
    // We will display a stripped out trimmed alpha-numeric version of it (if lang is eng)
    // so that garbage doesn't make it to the display.

    Log.v(TAG, "OCRED TEXT: " + recognizedText);

    if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase("eng")) {
        recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ");
    }

    recognizedText = recognizedText.trim();

    if (recognizedText.length() != 0) {
        _field.setText(_field.getText().toString().length() == 0 ? recognizedText : _field.getText() + " " + recognizedText);
        _field.setSelection(_field.getText().toString().length());
    }

    // Cycle done.
}


}
```

In this code TessBaseAPI is not importing. How it solve?

Comment: add NDK support

Comment: I have add ndk but it not solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to build that project yourself, follow the [instructions on the project website](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two#usage) to use the pre-built version by adding

```
compile 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.4'
```

to your app's build.gradle file.

Comment: @rmthesis Thank you for your help. I have developed the ocr app. It's working well. But it have no accuracy. when i convert image to text it not showing proper text. How to increase more accuracy and how to reduce size of the app.